# How to use token for login without refresh curl

Tags: php, curl

i'm trying to login to a website(remotely) lets say example.com/login  and that example.com/login use request token to login so i am getting request token from a url like this below

```
// code for getting token cookies etc

    $url = 'http://example.com/login/';

    $ch = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    $doc = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

// extract __RequestVerificationToken input field
     preg_match('#<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="(.*?)"#is', $doc, $match);


    $token = $match[1];

// code for redirect to dashboard 

$postinfo = "Email=".$username."&Password=".$password."&__RequestVerificationToken=".$token;
 // var_dump($token); //debug info
 $useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36";



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);

$html = curl_exec($ch);
echo $html;

if (curl_errno($ch)) print curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

So, i m getting the token but when trying to login with next curl request obviously the $token keep changing due to refresh so i want to know how i can login to url example.com/login with the same curl script so $token keep same?!

TIA!

Comment: You GET the page to get a token that is part of the login form, then you POST the login form on the page to get session cookies.  Those cookies should work until the session times out.  Use F12 in Chrome and check the box to keep network data between navigations to see how a browser does it.

Answer (score 1):

first off, a proper dom parser is much more reliable than a regex to extract the token, so use that.

```
$token = (new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($dom)))->query("//input[@name='__RequestVerificationToken']")->item(0)->getAttribute("value");
```

now, the token DEFINITELY changes for each new cookie session. and POSSIBLY changes for each failed login attempt, and POSSIBLY changes for each still-not-logged-in-page-refresh.

now, when you first get the token, you also get assigned a cookie session id. to "log in with the correct token", you must send that same session cookie id with the login request. the easiest way to do this, is to let curl handle cookies automatically, with `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` (ps, you don't need a dedicated file for the cookies, just set an emptystring and curl will take care of the cookies for you) - with that enabled, curl automatically sends the session cookie with the next login request.

and protip: whenever you're debugging curl code, enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE , it gives lots of useful information (like showing you all the cookies it received)

Comment: that dom parser didn't  worked for me don't know exactly why but that CURLOPT_VERBOSE had some really nice info which was helpful, also just to give update i'm able to get logged in, in remote site just need to redirected to that remote site after login, that will be done via curl right?!.
Thanks!!

Comment: well, if it is a HTTP header `Location: ` redirect, just use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` , and curl will follow the redirect automatically. but if it is a html/javascript redirect, you must follow the redirect manually with curl.

Comment: @AnasAhmedKhanNiazi and most likely, the dom parser didn't work because i wrote `loadHTML($dom)` - which is a typo, i _SHOULD_ have written `loadHTML($doc)` (where $doc is the html) - either that, or you don't have the php-xml extension installed

Comment: thanks for your comment, I tried Location: but that didn't worked saying headers already sent so i think i have to go with second part for the curl i've also updated my code in question so appreciate if you and other guys can comment on that too.

Comment: 1 obvious error in your updated code: $username/$password/$token is not urlencoded, so if the password (or any of them) contain characters with special meaning in urlencoded format, the server gets the wrong credentials, and you won't get logged in. this includes `&`,`=`, `@` (eg, if the $username is an email address, you won't get logged in), `,` (plain comma), `ÆØÅ`, and a lot of other characters. urlencode them, like `$postinfo = "Email=".urlencode($username)."&Password=".urlencode($password)."&__RequestVerificationToken=".($token);`

Comment: @AnasAhmedKhanNiazi another less obvious error, is that your regex extraction code cannot be trusted. if there are characters in the __RequestVerif‌​icationToken with special meaning in html format, they will be html encoded, this includes `&` (which is often encoded to `&amp;` - but it can be encoded in other ways too), `<` (which is often encoded to `&lt;`), `>` (which is often encoded to `&gt;`), and many other characters. your regex  code will NOT html decode them. my DOMXPath extractor would. but at the very least, change your code to  `$token = html_entity_decode($match[1]);`